# wrapbox with tabular has extraneous vertical space

Tags: verbatim, wrapfigure

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0in}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2in}|}
\hline
\begin{verbatim}
Some stuff here, hi mom
abcdefghijklmno
\end{verbatim} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box.  I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box.

Answer (score 1):

At the cost of greater overhead, `tcolorbox` gives you better control than using a tabular to 'frame' your verbatim text.  Plus, you can be more fancy with how these little snippets of verbatim text are framed.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig,tcolorbox}

% tcolorbox
\newenvironment{myverbatim}{%
  \begingroup\tcbverbatimwrite{\jobname.ex.txt}}%
{\endtcbverbatimwrite\endgroup}

% wrapfig.sty
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box. I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box.
This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box. I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box. XXX
\begin{myverbatim}
\begin{verbatim}
Some stuff here, hi mom
abcdefghijklmno `\verb'
\end{verbatim}
\end{myverbatim}
\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{0in}
 \begin{tcolorbox}[nobeforeafter,width=2in,colback=red!50!white] % <-- purposely odd colour chosen for 'colback'...
   \input{\jobname.ex.txt}
 \end{tcolorbox}
\end{wrapfigure}
This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box. I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box.
This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box. I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box.


\end{document}
```

And in case a plainer solution is more appealing, you could locally change `\topsep`, `\FrameSep`, and `\intextsep` to zero (or some small value).  The package `etoolbox` can help keep things tidy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig,framed,etoolbox}

% wrapfig
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
% framed
\setlength{\FrameSep}{2pt}
% etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{wrapfigure}{\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box. I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box.
This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box. I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box.
\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{r}{2in}
%\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\begin{framed}
\begin{verbatim}
Some stuff here, hi mom
abcdefghijklmno
\end{verbatim}
\end{framed}
\end{wrapfigure}
This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box. I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box.
This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box. I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box. XXX
% Compare:
\begin{framed}
\begin{verbatim}
Some stuff here, hi mom
abcde
\end{verbatim}
\end{framed}
This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box. I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box.
This doesn't quite do what I want, as the box ends up with extraneous vertical space between the top line of the text and the top of the box. I definitely want verbatim text and the ability to wrap the text outside around the box. XXX

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use other `verbatim`-providing packages like [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,wrapfig,fancyvrb}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2in}
  \vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}% Vertical adjustment above
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single,framerule=.4pt]
Some stuff here, hi mom
abcdefghijklmno
\end{Verbatim}
  \vspace*{-1.5\baselineskip}% Vertical adjustment below
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Vertical adjustments above/below may be required, but framing is done nicely by the package.